# Update statement with subquery in where clause

Tags: sql-server

Please help to build a UPDATE statement with subquery in where clause. I have two tables , Table ABC has Order ,OrderType, Key. Table XYZ has Key, Row Code. I need to update Table ABC , column Order type for Order passed from certain row codes. 
Base Data is like -

```
    Table - ABC
Order  OrderType  Key
1210    Onnet     AB-1210
2110    Onnet     AB-2110   
1234    Offnet    CD-1234
2345    Onnet     CD-2345
3456    Onnet     AB-3456

Table - XYZ
Key      RowCode
AB-1210  VOICE
AB-1210  VOIP
AB-1210  BVOICE
AB-2110  BVTO
AB-2110  VOIP
AB-2110  CBDE
CD-1234  ABCD
CD-1234  VCET
CD-1234  XYCD

Result
Order  OrderType           Key
1210    Onnet_VOICE       AB-1210
2110    Onnet_VOICE       AB-2110   
1234    Offnet            CD-1234
2345    Onnet             CD-2345
3456    Onnet             AB-3456
```

Update Statement -

```
UPDATE ABC
SET OrderType= 'Onnet_VOICE'
FROM ABC, XYZ
WHERE Order=  (SELECT Order FROM ABC WHERE ABC.Key = XYZ.Key  AND RowCode IN ('VOICE','VOIP') )
AND ABC.OrderType = 'Onnet'
```

Please help.

Comment: Order... what an awful name for a column.... I should have said [ORDER]

Comment: Since you're a learner, learn the right way:  Stop using commas to join tables, under any circumstance.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
UPDATE a SET 
    a.OrderType = 'Onnet_VOICE'
FROM
    dbo.ABC a
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
            dbo.XYZ x
        WHERE 
            a.[Key] = x.[Key]
            AND x.RowCode IN ('VOICE', 'VOIP')
        );
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. If I add one more filter in subquery where clause it's taking very long time on a large data set. Is there any way to simplify this query.
`UPDATE a SET 
    a.OrderType = 'Onnet_VOICE'
FROM
    dbo.ABC a
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
            dbo.XYZ x
        WHERE 
            a.[Key] = x.[Key]
            AND x.RowCode IN ('VOICE', 'VOIP')
OR (PRODUCT LIKE '%VOIP%' OR PRODUCT LIKE '%VOICE%' OR PRODUCT LIKE '%Audio%'
        );`

Comment: The "WHEE EXISTS" syntax is about as fast as you're likely to get. Thos get more speed, You should make sure that you have an index on XYZ with Key & RowCode as the keys (in that order).

Comment: Adding the proposed "OR"s to the where clause will only hurt performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UPDATE ... FROM JOIN ...` syntax:

```
UPDATE a
SET OrderType = 'Onnet_VOICE'
FROM ABC a
JOIN XYZ x
  ON a.[Key] = x.[Key]
WHERE x.RowCode IN ('VOICE','VOIP') 
  AND a.OrderType = 'Onnet';
```

Comment: @KeithL Thanks for spotting it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not giving correct result. We don't have 'Order' in both tables.

Comment: @LearnerBee So remove it from`ON` clause

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ABC
SET OrderType= 'Onnet_VOICE'
WHERE [Order] IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT [Order] FROM ABC A
JOIN XYZ  X ON X.[KEY] = A.[KEY]
WHERE A.[KEY] = X.[KEY] AND X.[RowCode] IN  ('VOICE','VOIP') AND A.[Ordertype] = 'Onnet')
```